# Remove all characters except

Tags: regex, r

My code takes a string and replaces all characters which are **not**:

- English letters
- Numbers
- `, / -`

I have tested it and it seems to generally work well enough. But it may have some catastrophic bug in it and/or can be simplified.

> ```
> x <- "dog/John is a cutting-edge pilot^¢„þ"
> gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9,-:space:]+", " ", x, perl = TRUE)
> "dog/John is a cutting-edge pilot "
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:space:` portion of the regex makes no sense, and probably does not do what you intend.

```
> x <- "abc:def."
> gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9,-:space:]", " ", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "abc:def."
```

Notice that the colon and period are still present after the substitution.

In fact, inside the character class, `,-:` means "all characters with ASCII codes from 44 (the comma) up to 58 (the colon)".

A literal hyphen must be the first or the last character in a character class; otherwise, it is treated as a range (like `A-Z`).

If you want a character class for whitespace, use `"\\s"` or `[:space:]`.

So, if you wanted to convert all consecutive strings of junk to a single space, preserving only letters, digits, commas, slashes, hyphens, and whitespace, you could write:

```
gsub("[^-,/a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+", " ", x, perl = TRUE)
```

or

```
gsub("[^-,/a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", " ", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Last line of answer is missing closing bracket `]`    2. In this answer, each unwanted character is separately converted to a blank. Applying this answer to the test string results in an answer with multiple blanks at the end.  The OP had a `+` so that multiple consecutive unwanted characters would become a single blank.